# How do I position a div below an image with changing height?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

In my new site I have an image set to width 100% and then a some text underneath that. How to I change the position of the text based on the height of the image?

```css
.pic {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.pic img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <img src="#" />
</div>
<div class="text">
  <h3>Some Important Message</h3>
</div>
```

As requested, here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sLx3n2vz/

Comment: please share fiddle of your working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try this:**

Remove all you css and add only

```
.pic{
    width:100%;
}
.pic img{
    width:100%;
}
.text{
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/sLx3n2vz/3/)

The way you are positioning your HTML element is wrong. Please correct it.

Comment: That is what I am trying to achieve but I still need my picture to be adjusting to the width of the screen.

Comment: Open the same link from the answer.